# The meaning (and grammatical form) of 'sortillo' in this text

Tags: grammar, word-choice, translation, phrase-choice

Torquato Tasso, La Gerusalemme Liberata, Canto Primo, 64:

*Vedi appresso spiegar l'alto vessillo*

*co 'l diadema di Piero e con le chiavi.*

*Qui settemila aduna il buon Camillo*

*pedoni, d'arme rilucenti e gravi,*

*lieto ch'a tanta impresa il Ciel sortillo,*

*ove rinovi il prisco onor de gli avi,*

*o mostri almen ch'a la virtú latina*

*o nulla manca, o sol la disciplina.*

Here the grammar and the general meaning are more or less clear to me. The only stumbling block here seems to be the word ***'sortillo'***. Is it a participle or a past tense form? Does it mean 'descended' or 'sent'?

Also, the emotional tone of the last two lines is a little bit unclear for me. Does Tasso show some irony there?

Comment: Sono abbastanza certo che si tratti di una forma poetica per *lo sortisse* (con il significato arcaico di *scegliesse*). Purtroppo non ho tempo di scrivere una risposta più dettagliata adesso.

Comment: Confermo l'ipotesi di Denis Nardin. Il significato è proprio quello indicato

Comment: Direi “lo sortì” (perché “sortisse”, @DenisNardin?) dove “sortire” ha il senso di “destinare” di 1b qui: http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sortire2 .

Comment: @DaG probabilmente hai ragione e si tratta di *lo sortì*, che a me sembra grammaticalmente scorretto ma che è stato sicuramente scelto per ragioni di metro.

Comment: ricordo un passo della Divina Commedia dove il verbo il buon Dante usa, nel link https://books.google.de/books?id=nhNgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=a+colui+ch%E2%80%99a+tanto+ben+sortillo+Piacque+di+trarlo+suso+a+la+mercede+Ch%E2%80%99el+merit%C3%B2+nel+suo+farsi+pusillo&source=bl&ots=nn-EA83eD3&sig=JjHoYKxXsuJccldyvhKFGgschAE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF6-D429bTAhUBuBQKHelOAz0Q6AEIRTAF#v=onepage&q=a%20colui%20ch%E2%80%99a%20tanto%20ben%20sortillo%20Piacque%20di%20trarlo%20suso%20a%20la%20mercede%20Ch%E2%80%99el%20merit%C3%B2%20nel%20suo%20farsi%20pusillo&f=false viene spiegato e parafrasato...

Answer (score 4):

The form *sortillo* is the same as *lo sortì* (passato remoto). The enclitic position of the pronoun is still used in modern Italian, with less frequency than in the past. Here one has to take into account that it's poetry, so there are several constraints with accent and rhyme.

The verb *sortire*, according to the [Treccani dictionary](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/sortire2/), means

> sortire<sup>2</sup> v. tr. [lat. sortire e sortiri, der. di sors sortis «sorte1»] (io sortisco, tu sortisci, ecc.), letter. – 1. a. Estrarre a sorte, sorteggiare: Chi de’ di voi combatter sortirete (Ariosto). b. Dare, assegnare in sorte; destinare: Dintorno al fosso vanno a mille a mille, Saettando qual anima si svelle Del sangue più che sua colpa sortille (Dante); Perch’a sì alto grado il ciel sortillo (Petrarca); quegl’ineffabili Giorni ... Che sì fugaci e brevi il cielo a noi sortì (Leopardi). 2. Avere in sorte: avere sortito dalla natura un grande ingegno; per estens., ottenere, conseguire: il suo tentativo di conciliazione non ha sortito alcun risultato; la cura ha sortito soltanto effetti negativi; felice si può chiamare quella repubblica, la quale sortisce un uomo sì prudente, che gli dia leggi ordinate (Machiavelli).

In the description you can see the same *sortillo* in a quote from Petrarch.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the word is an **archaic form**. Remember that Tasso lived in Renaissance and that work is a poem, so it suffers the constraints of rhyme.

According to http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sortire_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/ this *participle past tense* comes from Dante and is the verb **sortire**

> La semantica della voce si presenta assai omogenea, e può ordinarsi prevalentemente secondo i valori transitivi di " assegnare ", " concedere ", " destinare ", nell'interpretazione dei quali è sempre da sottintendere il principio dell'inaccessibile predestinazione divina, supremo ordine d'interventi diretti sia a regolare le vicende umane

So according to the context **sortire** can mean:

- Assegnare (to assign)
- Concedere (to grant)
- Destinare (to destinate, to decide that something will be assigned to one)

Comment: What do you mean by “participle past tense”?

Comment: To translate *destinare*, there is also an English verb “to destinate”.

Comment: Participio passato whatever is the English wording for it

Comment: “Participio passato” è *past participle* in inglese, ma “sortillo” non direi proprio che sia un participio passato.

Comment: dalla frase "che a tanta impresa (sforzo) il cielo ha sortito" beh sì mi ero concentrato sul participio dimenticando il verbo avere prima

Comment: Scusa, dove hai visto il verbo avere...? Hai letto i commenti già presenti sotto la domanda?